# Limit involving $\sum^n_{k=1} k^2$ in both the nominator and denominator.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How would you solve the following limit without using the $n^2$ sum formula:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\sum_{k=1}^n k^2)+(n+1)^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2}$

or written in another way:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 1 + \frac{(n+1)^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: write it as an approximation to an integral.

> As $n \to \infty$ $$\frac{(n+1)^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^3}}{\frac 1n \sum \frac{k^2}{n^2}} \to \frac{0}{\int_0^1 x^2 dx}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use L'Hopitals rule on the original equation, to get $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}=1$. The derivative of $(\sum_{k=1}^n k^2)$ is $n^2$.

Comment: You should be a little skeptical, because the derivative is not defined, but if you smooth it out, you can say that the asymptotic limit of the smooth approximation has a derivative between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2 $ so $n^2+o(n)$. This idea of smoothing out series is very interesting consider reading https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/#zeta-asym-1

Answer (score 1):

By the distributive property of limits,
$$1 + \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}{\frac{(n + 1)^2}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}}$$
Now, as we are in a limit that tends to infinity, we don't care cases of small numbers.
See that
$$f(n) = (n-1)^2 + (n-2)^2 +  n^2 - (n + 1)^2 = (n-1)^2 + (n-2)^2 - 2n-1$$
So,
$$f'(n)>0$$
So $f$ is increasing function for greater values of $n$. Now as $n$ tends to infinity, this difference is also tending to infinity.
Hence, we see that numerator is infinitely smaller than denominator and when $n$ is infinity, $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}{\frac{(n + 1)^2}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}}$ is $0$.
So, the original limit is $1$.

**Note:** $(n-1)^2$, $(n-2)^2$ and  $n^2$ are the last few terms of $\sum_{k=1}^n{k^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to keep things discrete, and are allowed to use the $n$ sum formula, note that for $m=n/2$

$$\frac{\sum_{h=0}^{m}(n-h)^2}{n^2}=\frac{\sum_{h=0}^{m}(n^2-2nh+h^2)}{n^2}\geq m-2\frac{m^2-m}{2n}=\frac{n+2}{4}$$

Thus

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}{n^2}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-m-1}k^2+\sum_{h=0}^{m}(n-h)^2}{n^2}>\frac{n+2}{4}$$

and

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}{n^2}=\infty$$

Finally, note

$$1+ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n+1)^2}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}=1+\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big(\frac{n^2}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}-\frac{2n}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}+\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}\Big)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Letting $a_n=(n+1)^2$ and $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$, you could also run [Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro,it%20for%20the%20first%20time.) on

$$\frac{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{b_n-b_{n-1}}=\frac{2n-1}{n^2}$$